# Android ArrayAdapter<> and ArrayList<>

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm trying to connect my ArrayList<> to my ArrayAdapter but Android Studio tells me that it cannot be apiled.

My code:

```
ArrayList<Events> list = new ArrayList<Events>();

    StableArrayAdapter1 adapter = new StableArrayAdapter1(this, list);



public class StableArrayAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Events> {
        public StableArrayAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Events> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Events user = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, parent, false);
            }
            TextView firsline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            TextView secondline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            firsline.setText(user.title);
            secondline.setText(user.place);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong? If it will needed I can add my Events class.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all i guess you are trying to set up a listview with a custom row correct?

So because you extend the `ArrayAdapter` and it tells you build constructor matching super the `super()` takes 3 parameters. Context, Layout id, list of (objects) what you extend.

Modify your adapter like this:

```
List<Events> list = new ArrayList<Events>();

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter1(YourActivity.this, R.layout.your_custom_row_layout_file, list);



public class StableArrayAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Events> {

        public StableArrayAdapter1(Context context,int layoutResId, List<Events> users) {
            super(context, R.layout.your_custom_row_layout_file, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Events user = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, parent, false);
            }

            TextView firsline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            TextView secondline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            firsline.setText(user.get(position).title);
            secondline.setText(user.get(position).place);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
StableArrayAdapter1 adapter = new StableArrayAdapter1(this.getActivity(),  MainActivity.list);
```

just need to getActivity(), hope that it will help someone in the future :P

Comment: and the `this` is suppose to refer to which class? Sir?